# grafana + prometheus conditional query

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have this query:

```
sum by (name) (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!="",
container_label_org_label_schema_group="$group"}
[1m])) / scalar(count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="$mode"})) * 100
```

`$group` is a list and values can be 'monitoring', 'web', or 'all'.

When `$group` is 'web', I'd like to replace `$group` with empty string. So the `container_label_org_label_schema_group` condition should be:

```
container_label_org_label_schema_group  = ''
```

When `$group` is 'all', then i want to match where `container_label_org_label_schema_group` is equal to 'monitoring' or empty string. Effectively something like:

```
container_label_org_label_schema_group  = '"monitoring"|""'
```

Not sure how to do do this with the promQL. It doesn't seem like the use of some AND operators to do pseudo IFs is working here. I'm thinking maybe substitution could be an option. But I don't not have success there either.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is just a [custom variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#add-a-custom-variable) with different labels and values for your variable. Would variable defined as `web :  , monitoring : monitoring, all : monitoring|` satisfy your needs? (notice double space between first colon and comma)

Comment: so $group stores the keys  you mentioned. you mean another set of variables to map the keys to what i want?  ok - but how would i use that in a query? can you refer to a dictionary type structure in a promsql?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. In grafana you can specify label for every value of you variable: it will be shown in drop down. But when substituted corresponding value will be used instead.

To do it you provide values for variable in format `label1 : value1, label2 : value2`.
[image]

And then simply use it in query like `$example`
[image]

For your exact problem use variable with the following values:

```
web :  , monitoring : monitoring, all : monitoring|
```

Please notice double space between first colon and comma.

Comment: How will this work if you want to create new variable which is conditioned on the value of another variable?

Comment: @SpaceX, _Custom_ variable cannot be created as chained variable dependent on other variables. For this you'll need _Query_ variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76387537/21363224) for more details.