# Grafana : Different Time range Specific Panel on the Same Dashboard

Tags: grafana, promql

If I am having custom from and to unixtimestamp, then how can I show the data between the custom time range for the specific graph in the dashboard?

Example:

in the variable

$interval_pre_from = 1696154400

$interval_pre_to = 1696327140

I want to show the cpu utilization between the time range using Prometheus(promql query) for only that specific panel in the dashboard.

How can we archive this? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your variables as is, because Grafana implicitly passes time range to Prometheus. But passed time range can be overridden with Query options *Relative time* and *Time shift* of panel.

*Relative time* means length of the time range to be shown on the panel. *Time shift* - shift from time range selected for dashboard. Important limitation: *Time shift* cannot be negative, so `$interval_pre_to` must be less then `$__to`, otherwise this approach won't work.

So, you need to [create to additional dependable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76385994). Let's call them `interval_pre_range` and `interval_pre_shift`.

For `interval_pre_range` you'll need *Query type*: **Query result**, *Query*: `vector($interval_pre_to - $interval_pre_from)`, and *Regex*: `{} (\d+) \d+`

For `interval_pre_shift` - *Query type*: **Query result**, *Query*: `time() - $interval_pre_to`.

After that, set Query options *Relative time* to `${interval_pre_range}s` and *Time shift* to `${interval_pre_shift}s`