# Submit multiple SQL queries in a dynamic way

Tags: sql, grafana, amazon-athena

I am using Grafana with the Amazon Athena data source.

My back-end is an AWS-S3-based Parquet data lake structured as follows:

```
[DeviceID]/[MessageName]/YYYY/MM/DD/filename.parquet
```

Each table is thus equivalent to a message from a specific device and contains sub signals of that message group within the columns of the Parquet file. An example query in Grafana may look as below:

```sql
SELECT
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval) as time,
    AVG(mysignal) as AVG_mysignal
FROM
    tbl_${device:csv}_mymessage
WHERE
    date_created BETWEEN $__rawTimeFrom('yyyy/MM/dd') AND $__rawTimeTo('yyyy/MM/dd')
    AND
    $__timeFilter(t)
GROUP BY
    $__timeGroup(t, $__interval)
```

The structure works well for performing visualizations from a single device and e.g. creating separate panels per message.

However, for some use cases I want to show information across multiple devices, e.g. all devices or say 100 different devices. For example, I might want to display the average signal value of `Speed` from the table `MessageSpeed` grouped to a daily basis across all devices. However, this is not trivial to do in a single SQL query like the one above, as I do not want to perform a table join across all the device tables (it would be extremely time consuming).

I am considering whether it may be practical to use some form of parameterization logic to submit multiple parallel SQL queries within Grafana in order to perform the relevant query from each device table, then visualize the results from this in a single panel.

However, I struggle to find a method to do this within Grafana (as well as other Athena-supporting tools). Basically, I would want to be able to provide a list of `DeviceID` values to a function that then runs the above query once per device and returns the results, but in a dynamic way, with the number of executions depending on the original device list provided.

Comment: Can you create a view, that would contain all signals, and their respective device id as column (not as join, that you suggested, but rather union of all your current tables)?

Comment: One route we do consider is in general to solve this through periodic data aggregation, e.g. creating aggregated tables/views that contain the data we need across devices. But this adds a separate layer of complexity. Therefore we initially wanted to investigate if this could be done in a 'dynamic way' on-the-fly. For example, a dashboard end user may select 20 devices from a dropdown. We would like to parse this list of devices to the Grafana panel in a way so that the results are extracted for those devices. However, I can't see how to create a UNION query in a dynamic way in the panel?

Comment: I don't think you can create a union query dynamically. The closest thing to your goal that Grafana can is a repetition of a panel (or row) based on multivalue variable. But I don't think it will get you full result.

Comment: Ok I guess what I was looking for would essentially be the equivalent of the 'duplicate panel' functionality, but just at the query level, i.e. 'duplicate query' based on a variable template selection. But I guess this does not exist?

Comment: As far as I know - no, nothing like this exists.

Comment: Ok, just to check: If we abstract this away from Grafana, is it somehow possible in an SQL query to define it so that a loop is performed across a list ala: `for device in ["X","Y","Z"] execute [SQL query with device variable]`?

Comment: If different devices mean different tables, this is only possible through dynamic SQL. As I understand, [Athena supports it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/sql-execute.html).

Comment: After second thought, I guess something like this can even be done in Grafana: through creating second variable, that would contain a full SQL query based on list of tables. General idea of dependent variables described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76387537/21363224), but instead of simple case, you'll need to split your input into array, and then create full blown union query out of it. Not sure if it's possible in Athena, and even if it is - will be tricky to say the least.

Comment: The dynamic SQL is a good idea, but I seem unable to use a table name as the "?" in the SQL syntax. Are you able to get that to work with Athena, or is the "?" only possibly e.g. a filter value?